# c++ boost:asio convert socket to stream?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio, iostream

I am using `boost::asio` in both async and sync way. One thread in my application `async_accept` a socket, and the other thread read/write from that socket synchronously.

AFAIK `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` object can be created by connecting to an endpoint directly. I am looking for a way to get a stream object from a socket obj, so I can make my communication lib generic. Is there a way to get that object from an socket obj?

Comment: is there any reason that you must keep the socket explicitly, and not just use the iostream as per the example here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/daytime_server.cpp ? The example uses a synchronous accept but the async_accept will allow for the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid internally mixing sync with async. Externally emulate one of those using other. Since asio is async use it async and emulate sync by waiting async operation to complete.